# Create custom typedJS animations by mattboldt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I actually new to javascript, & I confused to create custom amimation for typedJS.

Example, First sentence : `Blabla first`, Second sentence:  `Blabla second`, Third Sentence: `Blabla third`,, What I want is block the `first` word like block with mouse then remove the `first` word only then write the  `second` word without write `Blabla` again , and continus until the last sentence, any suggestion?